# How to get Razor and WebPages support in VS 2012 Express for Web?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web the other day and it's very awkward-feeling trying to write sites now because there isn't any intellisense or razor support and no syntax highlighting for razor code.

When the installation completed I got a message but I accidently clicked the OK button before I even began reading it, but I did get the general gist of it and it was asking me about Razor/WebPages, so I'm thinking it was asking if I wanted to install an update for it (maybe) but I'm not sure. But I know I clicked the OK button so it should've done it if that's what it was talking about.

But I tried searching for something to download but in WebPlatform Installer everything already shows up as being 'Installed'. So I'm not sure what to do to get the latest WebPages/Razor support in VS 2012 Express for Web?

Some things I've already tried are:

- Repair the installation
- Completely uninstall VS 2012 ex for web and reinstall
- Re-download and install ASP.NET WebPages and re-install it

None of them have worked.

I just tried opening an existing solution again and was shown the same message as before. It said VS requires missing components and asked if I wanted to install them so I can open the solution (A website written in webpages/razor 3), it then said it will download Webpages framework with razor 3, it opened WebPI and webPI is now saying:

"Microsoft WebPI couldn't find the product you tried to install. Either the link you clicked is incorrect or you may be overriding your feed with a different feed."

So I went and searched for it in WebPI and not a single related result appears for any of the following:

- webpages
- web pages
- razor
- razor 3
- ASP.NET WebPages
- ASP.NET Razor

Comment: Try downloading this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34600